# CSS Text-Align Center not working items are appearing beneath eachother

Tags: css

Hey so I have a div containing 3 links which have a background url image making them appear as an image

Here is my css classes

```
    /* calculate button */
.fc-calculate {text-align: center; padding: 12px 0; display: }

.fc-calculate-button {margin: 0 auto; width:200px;}

.fc-calculate-button a {line-height: 21px; height: 21px; background: url(../../images/SOURCE/btn_grn_r.gif) 100% 0 no-repeat; width: auto; display: block; float: left; padding-right: 30px;}
.fc-calculate-button a span {display: block; float: left; background: url(../../images/SOURCE/btn_grn_l.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; line-height: 21px; height: 21px; padding-left: 12px; color: #fff;}
```

And mark up as follows

```
    <div class="fc-calculate">
    <div class="fc-calculate-button">
      <sc:link field="Link One" cssClass="">
        <span class="btnspan">
          <sc:text select="." field="Link One Text" />
        </span>
      </sc:link>
    </div>
    <!-- /fc-calculate-button -->


    <div class="fc-calculate-button">
      <sc:link field="Link Two" cssClass="">
        <span class="btnspan">
          <sc:text select="." field="Link Two Text" />
        </span>
      </sc:link>
    </div>
    <!-- /fc-calculate-button -->
</div>
```

The issue is that instead of the links appearing next to eachother and centered they are appearing beneath eachother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're floating your anchor and your spans but not your `.fc-calculate-button` class, if you want to display both containers side by side and center them on its container try this:

**CSS**

```
.fc-calculate {
    text-align:center;
}

.fc-calculate-button {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}
```

Comment: Cool that worked can you explain what *display means never seen that before

Comment: @StevieB it is a hack to target IE7 since it does not support the `display:inline-block` property so we use the `inline` property instead with the same results, this way you will have the same look across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

divs are inherently display:block. Try adding this:

```
.fc-calculate {margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; padding: 12px 0;}
.fc-calculate-button {display:inline; margin: 0 auto; width:200px;}
```

Comment: Ok I did that and now they are next to eachother but no longer centered both are left aligned

Comment: see my edited answer. You probably need auto left and right margin on the parent container. Kinda tough to see without a working page. :)

Comment: Yeah I understand I tried the above but again they are now next to eachother but not centered. Btw where u missing the display:value in the fc-calculate class

Comment: Hmmm... any chance you could post this on jsfiddle or http://dabblet.com/? I can fix this very quickly with an inspection of  your code. I just copied your fc-calc class... didn't see the empty display property haha.